# How to extends @types/mocha Context class

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, .d.ts

I have a few base variable that creates at beforeEach hook. Of course I have no types for this variables in test so I wrote my own d.ts

```
declare namespace Mocha {
    class Context {
        client: IClient;
        bus: IBus;
        testNumber: number;
        connectionParams: ConnectionParams;
    }
}
```

And I include path to a file in `files` section in .tsconfig. But I still have no info about this fields in tests. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare global {
  namespace Mocha {
    interface Context {
      customProperty: string;
    }
  }
}
```